# what is the connection string using alwaysdata with scala

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

i am using Scala with play and slick.

```
    scalaVersion := "2.13.10"

libraryDependencies += guice
libraryDependencies += "org.scalatestplus.play" %% "scalatestplus-play" % "5.1.0" % Test
libraryDependencies +=  "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "42.5.0"
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick" % "5.1.0"
```

and in my application.conf:

```
slick.dbs.default.profile = "slick.jdbc.PostgresProfile$"
slick.dbs.default.db.driver = "org.postgresql.Driver"
slick.dbs.default.db.url = "postgresql-stevapp.alwaysdata.net:5432"
slick.dbs.default.db.user = "XXXX"
slick.dbs.default.db.password="YYYYY"
```

i got this error [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL should be a JDBC URL in the form `jdbc:postgres://postgresql-stevapp.alwaysdata.net:5432/mydb?someParam=someValue`.